# Why ping not works through Interface name but works through Interface address?

Tags: ubuntu, ping

I use a USB-Ethernet Adapter which gets recognized as `eth1` in the target.
I then set an IP for `eth1` using the command

```
ifconfig eth1 YY.YY.YY.YY
```

When I use

```
ping -I eth1 XX.XX.XX.XX
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
mx6q:~# ping -I eth1 192.168.2.35
PING 192.168.2.35 (192.168.2.35): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 192.168.2.35 ping statistics --- 3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

it's not working, whereas when I use

```
ping -I YY.YY.YY.YY XX.XX.XX.XX
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
mx6q:~# ping -I 192.168.2.99 192.168.2.35
PING 192.168.2.35 (192.168.2.35) from 192.168.2.99: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.2.35: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.765 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.35: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.437 ms
^C
--- 192.168.2.35 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
```

it *is* working.

What should I do to ping through interface name?

**IFCONFIG**

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:07:40:53:dd:1b  
          inet addr:192.168.2.99  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::207:40ff:fe53:dd1b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4754 (4.6 KiB)  TX bytes:1376 (1.3 KiB)
```

Comment: How to configure the hosts ? - I am a beginner.

Comment: What changes I've to do in it ?

Comment: This works for me.  Please say more about how it's "not working".  Do you get an error message?  What does the ping print out about what it's doing in the two cases?  Does it help if you add -n to either command?

Comment: @Rahul I don't think this has _anything_ to do with his hosts file, since he's not using host names.

Comment: It is working in my case

Comment: I've added the output to the question @ http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/74442/map

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the interface name is present on your machine. Check by doing `ifconfig` or `ip addr show` or `ip link show` commands.

You can also do some troubleshooting using `ip route show`  and `traceroute -i` commands.

It is working as shown below:

```
[iahmad@ijaz-cms ~]$ ping -I enp0s25 www.google.com

PING www.google.com (172.217.18.100) from 137.138.52.207 enp0s25: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from zrh04s05-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.18.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=4.88 ms
64 bytes from zrh04s05-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.18.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=4.97 ms
64 bytes from zrh04s05-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.18.100): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=5.01 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.885/4.958/5.019/0.055 ms


[iahmad@ijaz-cms ~]$ ping -I 137.138.52.207 www.google.com

PING www.google.com (172.217.18.100) from 137.138.52.207 : 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from zrh04s05-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.18.100): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=4.98 ms
64 bytes from zrh04s05-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.18.100): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=4.93 ms
64 bytes from zrh04s05-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.18.100): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=4.96 ms
64 bytes from zrh04s05-in-f4.1e100.net (172.217.18.100): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=4.98 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.939/4.966/4.983/0.017 ms
```

Comment: It is present in ifconfig. But the ping command doesn't work if we give the interface name instead of interface IP